# agGrid autoHeightCalculator holds rendering

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

While using agGridReact faced issue with autoHeightCalculator. After the data has been fetched this script takes over 10 sec. before rendering 3000 rows of data. Is there some option to switch it off or any idea how to reduce this time interval?

Answer (score 0):

Check ag-grid property "autoHeight", autoHeightCalculator() running if it's true.